# How to convert a JSONObject to a object contains java.util.Set field

Tags: java, json

There is a model class:

```
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private Set<String> authors = new HashSet<String>();  //Set field

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Set<String> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
    public void setAuthors(Set<String> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [authors=" + authors + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

And I execute the function below:

```
public void test3() {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId("T2");
    Set<String> authors = new HashSet<String>();
    authors.add("Tom");
    authors.add("King");
    book.setAuthors(authors );

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(book);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);

    Book b = (Book) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Book.class);
    System.out.println(b.toString());

}
```

It cannot convert jsonObject to Book object, and there will be a exception.
How can I convert jsonObject to Book object successful?

Comment: What is the exception? and what does your json look like.

Comment: The exception is:net.sf.json.JSONException: Error while setting property=authors type interface java.util.List
 at net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.java:468)
 at net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.java:242)
 at com.augmentum.ot.Test.test3(Test.java:54)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)...

Comment: try using [GSon](http://www.json.org/) for conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Gson` :

```
Book b = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, Book.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answre, I have solved the problem. At first I used json-lib-2.1.jar, and then I replace it with json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar.